# How to Inject a wallet into the browser from Mobile (react-native)?

Tags: react-native, web3js, ethers.js

I have created a mobile wallet and am I attempting to inject the wallet provider into a web view instance. I want the wallet to mimic how Metamask would connect.

This is the code I am using currently. And the image below shows that the browser sees an injected wallet, but the site cannot seem to link to this `window.ethereum` instance.

```js
import React, {Component, useEffect, useContext, useState} from 'react'
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview'

import {ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native-paper'

import '@ethersproject/shims'
import {ethers} from 'ethers'

export const Web3View = ({url, address, privateKey}) => {
  const nodeProvider = 'https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org/'
  const [injectedJavaScript, setInjectedJavaScript] = useState(null)

  function handleMessage(event) {
    const message = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data)
    if (message.type === 'accounts') {
      setAccounts(message.payload)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (privateKey == '') {
      console.log('NO PK')
      return
    }

    console.log('url=', url)
    const providerMainnet = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(nodeProvider)
    let walletProviderMainnet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, providerMainnet)

    const injectedJavaScript = `
                window.ethereum = {};
                window.ethereum.isMetaMask = true;
                window.ethereum.isConnected = function() { return true };
                window.ethereum.provider = ${JSON.stringify(providerMainnet)};
                window.ethereum.wallet = {};
                window.ethereum.wallet.provider = ${JSON.stringify(
                  walletProviderMainnet.provider
                )};
                window.ethereum.wallet.address = '${address}';
                window.ethereum.selectedAddress = '${address}';
                window.ethereum.eth_requestAccounts = async function(tx) {
                    return '${address}';
                };
                window.ethereum.wallet.signTransaction = async function(tx) {
                    const signedTx = await walletProviderMainnet.signTransaction(tx);
                    return signedTx;
                };
                window.ethereum.request = function(args) { return window.ethereum.send(args[0], args[1]) };
                window.ethereum.send = function(method, params) {
                    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                        window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
                            type: 'bsc',
                            payload: {
                                method: method,
                                params: params,
                            }
                        }));
                        window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
                            if (event.data.type === 'ethereum' && event.data.payload.id === params[0]) {
                                if (event.data.payload.error) {
                                    reject(event.data.payload.error);
                                } else {
                                    resolve(event.data.payload.result);
                                }
                            }
                        }, { once: true });
                    });
                };
                window.ethereum.enable = async function() {
                    let accounts = await window.ethereum.wallet.provider.listAccounts();
                    accounts = window.ethereum.wallet.address
                    return accounts;
                };
                window.ethereum.send('eth_accounts').then(accounts => {
                    window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
                        type: 'accounts',
                        data : accounts
                    }));
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log('Error:', error);
                });
            `
    setInjectedJavaScript(injectedJavaScript)
  }, [url, privateKey])

  return injectedJavaScript == null ? (
    <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
  ) : (
    <WebView
      //userAgent={"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3"}
      source={{uri: url}}
      style={{flex: 1, width: '100%'}}
      startInLoadingState={true}
      renderLoading={() => <ActivityIndicator size='large' />}
      javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
      onMessage={(event) => {
        console.log('Webview event', event.nativeEvent.data)
      }}
      injectedJavaScript={injectedJavaScript}
    />
  )
}
```

Upon typing this up stack overflow has suggested [**Ethereum provider**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@walletconnect/ethereum-provider) which I am now looking into, but please let me know if anyone has some insight.

[image: Wallet image]

Answer (score 0):

1. https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#injectedjavascriptbeforecontentloaded
   i works well used `react-native-webview@12.1`,nor `react-native-webview@11.13.0`，u can try switch react-native-webview version。
2. https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/356
   `document.addEventListener("message", handler)`diff on Android/IOS

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).